# A general question about Modelica initialization

Tags: modelica

How to set values to all the variables that could be possibly used as iteration variables, for example, there is a heat exchanger which includes a few connectors, and each connector includes a few variables, I can't know which variables could be used as iteration variables, when dealing with initialization, do I need to set values to every variable so that no matter which variable is chosen as iteration variable, there is a reasonable value?

Comment: Initialization, selection of states and iteration variables, tearing and more is done differently by every tool, and for most tools it is not fully documented. 
For Dymola 2020x, you should read UserManual_1B, section 2.8 as well as UserManual_1A, section 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marvel,

I think that you are a bit on the wrong track for finding a solution: setting values to all variables that possibly could become iteration variables is often too many, and will lead to errors and problems. But I think I can give you some useful advice in any case.

1. Alias variables: there are many alias variable sin Modelica models. You should always try to only select one of them to set start values.
2. Feedback between start values and iteration variables: most Modelica tools will prefer to select iteration variables that have start values set. Selecting fewer thus can guide the algorithm towards selecting good one. Therefore: don't overdo it.
3. General advice for selecting iteration variables. For a pure ODE, the states will always be a complete set of start variables, even if sometimes not the best one. For DAE you can start with the following exercise: think of all equations that result from a singular perturbation of the complete physics as differential equations with states. For example, in a heat exchanger, you need to consider the dynamic momentum balance and not the most often used static reduction to an algebraic pressure loss only, i.e. add the mass flow as a state. Similar in chemical reactions: think of it as Kinetics, not equilibrium reactions. That gives you a pretty good starting point, even though often not the best one.

If your troubles don't quite resolve from that, I recommend that you contact us via www.modelon.com: we have advanced ways of dealing with hard initialization and steady state problems in our Modelic tool. :-)

Comment: The tool you mentioned is OPTIMICA Compiler based on JModelica?  Could you give me a simple explanation about how it deals with the hard initialization problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a simplest way to answer your question, working quite well with fluid models.
Giving the fact that you are using a dynamic model, what you need to initialize are the state variables of your system. To know the state variables, either you know the type of model you are wirking with or you can dig through them using options like 'List continuous time states selected' in Dymola (I do not know about other tools), giving you the state variables in the translation log.
In case of fluid models, most of the times those are pressure and energy (enthalpy or temperature). All other variables will be calculated based on them.

For complex (or not) models, this approach show limits, which can sometimes be solved by changing/correcting the structure of the model.

Static models are something else...

Hope this can help :)

Comment: I guess the ultimate method is always testing each component.  Coding is like a labor work right now.